# Rouche's theorem to find number of zeroes of slightly perturbed polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a way to use Rouche's theorem to do the following: Say we have $P_{t}(z)$, an $n$-degree polynomial whose coefficients are continuous in $t$, with multiple distinct zeroes at time $t_{0}$, and if we further assume that as we perturb $t$ slightly, the degree of the polynomial stays the same, can we say there exists some time $t$ sufficiently close to $t_{0}$ so that $P_{t}$ also has the same number of distinct roots?

I think it is possible to prove it has distinct roots still (though I'm not sure of the exact details, maybe Hurwitz's theorem?), but is there a way to maybe see that the number of zeroes is in fact the same? Rouche's theorem comes to mind, but I'm not sure what a suitable second function would be. It seems intuitively obvious.

Comment: The roots are continuous functions of the coefficients.

Comment: How do we know that? Is there an expression you can point me to?

Comment: http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~alen/articles/polyroots.pdf